# 'apt-get install' ignores my specification to install particular version of package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

I'd like to install particular version of libstd++6 with following command:

```
# apt-get install libstdc++6=4.9.0-8  -V
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

The following extra packages will be installed:
   libstdc++6 (4.8.2-16)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 216 not upgraded.
```

It gives no error, but apt keeps version that was already installed.
And also it refers to this package as "extra".

There's no apt preferences set in /etc/apt/preferences.d.
And the desirable version is definetely available through our local mirror.
(If I try to run "apt-get download libstdc++6=4.9.0-8" it will download exactly desirable version.)

System info:

```
# cat /etc/issue.net
"Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid"
# uname -a
Linux www27 3.13-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.13.7-1 (2014-03-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux.
# dpkg -l |egrep -i "apt|dpkg"
ii  apt                                   0.9.16.1                     amd64        commandline package manager
ii  dpkg                                  1.17.6                       amd64        Debian package management system
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that libstd++6_4.9.0-8 depends on gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.0-8). However I got installed gcc-4.9-base of version 4.9.0-7.

I figured it out after I tried to install previously downloaded package with dpkg.

```
# apt-get download libstdc++6=4.9.0-8
# dpkg -i libstdc++6_4.9.0-8_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 64836 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libstdc++6_4.9.0-8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (4.9.0-8) over (4.8.2-16) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:amd64:
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.0-8); however:
  Version of gcc-4.9-base:amd64 on system is 4.9.0-7.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++6:amd64
```

Does anyone know how to debug apt or make it's output more verbose?(I want to know it for the future)